# Filter mongoose collection based on latitude longitude in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongoose, filter, collections, geometry

I am trying to filter the collection using latitude, and longitude. But after trying this code getting an error.I tried to create the index as well from the model class. but still the error is the same, How to fix this error?

```
Post.index({location:'2dsphere'})
```

[image]

```
let auth = await User.findOne({'id':ownerId}).exec();

console.log('Auth---',auth);



const center = [12.8965821,77.5973652];

const query = {location: { $near: { $geometry: { type: "Point", coordinates: center }, $maxDistance: 1000*1000 } } };



Post.find(query).then(result=>{
  return res.status(200).json({success:true,message:result});
}).catch(error=>{
  return res.status(400).json({success:false,message:error});
})
```